# BootStrap Grid not working properly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I've been recently working on a website with bootstrap and for some reason my grid that i've set up isn't fully working. Basically I have a website thats 2 columns, one column takes 4 grid spaces and the other 8 spaces.  Once the size of the page reaches mobile, the width of my 8 grid picture screws up.  Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- Website Template by freewebsitetemplates.com -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css" type="text/css">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">

            <style>

            .header{
            padding:0;}




            .leftcol{

                width:100%;
                height:800px;

                    }

            .rightcol{
                width:112.3%;
                height:800px;
                }

            .text{
                color:black;
                position:absolute;
                top:10%;
                left:35%;
            }

            .contact_image{
                width:50%;
                position:absolute;
                top:70%;
                left:27%;
            }

            </style>
</head>


<body>
<div class="container">


<header class="row">

<div class="header col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
<img  id="papa" src="newImages/papaupdated.png">
</div>


<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
<img src="newImages/remaxlogo.jpg">


</div>

</header>

<div class=" navigation navbar navbar-default row">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="opportunities.php">Opportunities</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="propertymanagement.php">Property Management</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="aboutjay.php">About Jay</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="community.php">Community</a>
                </li>
                <li class="selected">
                    <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
</div>

<div class=" row col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 hidden-xs" >
<img class="row leftcol" src="newImages/leftsidebackground.jpg">
</div>



<div class="  row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <img class="rightcol row" src="images/greyimage.jpg">

         <div class="text col-lg-12">
          <p> Email me at <a href="mailto:jay@jaycousins.com">jay@jaycousins.com</a></p>
                    <p>(250) 751-1223 Office</p>
                    <p>(250) 751-1300 Fax</p>
                    <p><span style="color:red;">RE/MAX</span> Jay Cousins Realty</p>
                    <p>#1-5140 Metral Drive</p>
                    <p >Nanaimo B.C. Canada</p>
                    <p >(250) 751-1223 Bus.</p>
                    <p>(250) 751-1300 Fax.</p>
                    <p >"Each Office Independently Owned & Operated"</p></div>

                    <img class="contact_image" src="newImages/cityImage.jpg">  
</div>


<footer class=" row col-lg-12">

            <p>
                &copy; Copyright 2012. All rights reserved
            </p>
</footer>
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you set 'rightcol' to be wider than 100%?

Comment: Because for some reason the image won't cover the entire container size.  Unless I set it higher than 100

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `row` in  `class="  row col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"` . Use a wrapping div with class `row`.

Also use class `row` only for footer and add inner div with class `col-lg-12`.

In header, it is correct.

Comment: Thank you, is there any reason why, when i take out the row and add a seperate div as a wrapper that the grey and dark grey images seperate? I then have to add 110% to the width of the darkgrey, which doens't seem right, but it works?

Comment: I am not able to check this as you have not shared all the css. Anyway adding row and col class in same element is wrong. Also it is not a good idea to give width greater than 100%. If required, you can add additional wrapping divs outside `row` to accomplish your requirements.

Comment: @Kipperman -  One of the classes for that div probably has padding. You also shouldn't use the 'row' class in image tags.

Answer (score 0):

**Kipperman**, Hopefully this can help get you on the right track here.
I have added a way for you to get your images into your `divs` so you don't have the problem you mentioned. 
I have coded it so everything says within the screen size.

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzn297jj/1/)**.

```
.image{
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/900x500/e67e22/ffffff&amp;text=image');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'll take a look.  I'm quite new to bootstrap so I appreciate it